# Multiple ring buffer as annulus?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, buffer

I'm looking at plant biomass values in 2m intervals (center to 30m) around several waypoints. I've extracted the zonal stats as a table, however each of the buffers also includes the smaller increment buffer values (i.e the 8-10m interval also includes the center-8m values). Is there any way to create multiple annulus around each point so that I'm isolating the values per interval and not the total? Using ArcMap/GIS 10.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

[The Multiple Ring Buffer Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/multiple-ring-buffer.htm) is what you are looking for. Make sure dissolve all is on.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I knew it was something pretty simple. I had used the multiple ring buffer tool but did not have the dissolve all on. Thanks very much!

Comment: @JenniferDalton  if this post answered your question please accept it.

Comment: So the dissolve all option works to create rings that are JUST within the intervals. Thank you! But it merges the statistics for all of my 37 waypoints. For example, all 2m interval values are then reported as one average. Is there anyway to maintain the statistics for each waypoint i.e. 37 mean values for the 0-2m interval, 37 mean values for the 2-4m, etc. interval

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of what you are talking about? This is a little difficult to visualize. Are you saying zonal statistics merges the waypoints?

Comment: I think dodahee means is there a way to buffer in a way that maintains the rings as separate features for each point even if the buffers overlap, e.g. a series of doughnuts instead of swiss cheese.